# How to set all lines as breakpoints in CLion?

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, clion

I am using CLion to debug C programs, however I keep finding myself in the situation of needing to set all lines as breakpoints. Currently the only way I can set all lines as breakpoints is by manually marking each line as a breakpoint, one line at a time. I looked for alternative ways to set lines as breakpoints and the only thing i found was that I could use keyboard shortcuts to toggle breakpoints and I could view all breakpoints. I also tried highlighting all lines in the file and then toggling breakpoints, but it would only toggle breakpoints for a single line - the line selected right before highlighting all lines in the file.

Is there or is there not currently any way to set all lines as breakpoints in one go in CLion?

Also, I considered asking this on superuser.com, however there were ~200x more questions (13 vs 3275) about CLion on StackOverflow so I asked it here instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting all lines as breakpoints would be the same as stepping through a program. So set a breakpoint at the beginning of main and step through.

Comment: not true, some frameworks don't have really good entry point location, eg flex - lexical analysis tool